# WinError 10060 when trying check email validity

Tags: python-3.x, email-validation

I based on a code that I found on the internet (the same appears in many different sources).
I tried this in my office and it worked. But now I'm at home (working from home), and I get a [WinError 10060].

The exact error is (I'm Brazilian, then there is a portuguese setence):

TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] Uma tentativa de conexão falhou porque o componente conectado não respondeu corretamente após um período de tempo ou a conexão estabelecida falhou porque o host conectado não respondeu

```
import re
import dns.resolver
import socket
import smtplib

email_address = test@anydomain.com

#Step 1: Check email
#Check using Regex that an email meets minimum requirements, throw an error if not
addressToVerify = email_address
match = re.match('^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z] {2,4})$',addressToVerify)

if match == None:
    print('Bad Syntax in ' + addressToVerify)
    raise ValueError('Bad Syntax')

#Step 2: Getting MX record
#Pull domain name from email address
domain_name = email_address.split('@')[1]

#get the MX record for the domain
records = dns.resolver.query(domain_name, 'MX')
mxRecord = records[0].exchange
mxRecord = str(mxRecord)

#Step 3: ping email server
#check if the email address exists

# Get local server hostname
host = socket.gethostname()

# SMTP lib setup (use debug level for full output)
server = smtplib.SMTP()
server.set_debuglevel(1)

# SMTP Conversation
server.connect(mxRecord)
server.helo(host)
server.mail('me@domain.com')
code, message = server.rcpt(str(addressToVerify))
server.quit()

# Assume 250 as Success
if code == 250:
    print('Y')
else:
    print('N')
```

Comment: can you please paste the exact error?

Comment: The exact error is (I'm Brazilian, then there is a portuguese setence):

TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] Uma tentativa de conexão falhou porque o componente conectado não respondeu
corretamente após um período de tempo ou a conexão estabelecida falhou
porque o host conectado não respondeu

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's due to proxies.

Remove any proxy in your Environment variable or bash profile/terminal if you are using Linux system.
Open Command terminal as an Administrator or run as sudo in case of Linux terminal and then try.